# Data saves only on the first row in the lightning datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-datatable

I have a lightning datatable with a save event. After i click the save button, the inputted data always saves on the first row of the table, regarding the position of the row that i just edited. Example if i edit row 4 and save, the value saves on the first row.

This is the save event (it calls a validationRule method):

```
saveHandleAction(event) {
       
        // Validate the data
        let hasErrors = this.validationRule(event);
        if (!hasErrors) {
            // Update the data2 array based on the draftValues
            event.detail.draftValues.forEach((draftRow) => {
                let index = this.data2.findIndex((selectedRow) => selectedRow.Id === draftRow.Id);
                if (index !== -1) {
                    Object.assign(this.data2[index], draftRow);
                }
            });
            // Clear the draftValues
            this.draftValues = [];
            // Dispatch a success toast event
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Records Updated Successfully!!',
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );
        }
    }
```

this is the ValidationRule method.

```
validationRule(event) {
        let hasErrors = false;
        let selectedRow = event.detail.selectedRows;
        let draftValues = event.detail.draftValues;
        // Loop through each row in draftValues
        for (let i = 0; i < draftValues.length; i++) {
            const currentDraftValue = draftValues[i];
            const currentRow = this.data2.find(row => row.Id === currentDraftValue.Id);
            if (currentRow) {
                currentRow.invoiceReportedDueDate = currentDraftValue.invoiceReportedDueDate || currentRow.invoiceReportedDueDate;
                // Convert date strings to Date objects
                var invoiceReportedDueDate = new Date(currentRow.invoiceReportedDueDate);
                var dueDate = new Date(currentRow.dueDate);
                // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
                var dif = invoiceReportedDueDate - dueDate;
                // Calculate the difference in days
                var d = dif / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
        
                if (d > 30
                    && !currentRow.invoiceDunningLevelIcon.includes("dunning-level-green")
                    && !currentRow.invoiceDunningLevelIcon.includes("dunning-level-blue")
                    && (this.userRole == this.USER_ROLE_CSC_SUPERVISOR || this.userRole == this.USER_ROLE_CSC_AGENT)) {
                    hasErrors = true;
                }

            } else {
                console.log(`No matching row found for draftValue with Id: ${currentDraftValue.Id}`);
            }
        }
        if (hasErrors) {
            try {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error',
                        message: EL_Reported_Due_Date_After_One_Month_Defer,
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                );
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error in validationRule loop:', error);
            }
        }
        return hasErrors;
    }
```

I don't know where the problem is, can someone help?

Comment: Looks good to me. Have you added key-field="Id" In your DataTable tag?

Comment: Yes, it was added.

<lightning-datatable
                            draft-values={draftValues}
                            key-field="id"
                           .....
                            sorted-direction={sortDirection2}
                            sorted-by={sortedBy2}
                            onsort={onHandleSortOpenInvoicesForContractAccount}
                            onrowaction={callRowAction}
                            onsave={saveHandleAction}>
                    </lightning-datatable>